# BSON size of every MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to know the BSON size of approximately 50 documents. How could I do it? Is there any query command that could do this?

```
db.getCollection("some_collection").aggregate([
    {"$match": {}},
    {"$limit": 50},
    {"$project":
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "created_at": "$created_at",
            "updated_at": "$updated_at",
            "size": Object.bsonsize("$updated_at"),  // This line is not runnable
        }
    }
])
```

---

### Solution

I'm updating the solution here, because this question is mistakenly flagged as duplicated by the moderator.

```
db.getCollection("some_collection").find({}).limit(50).sort({"_id": -1}).forEach(doc => {
    const size = Object.bsonsize(doc); 
    print(doc._id, size)
})
```

Comment: is there any reason you are using aggregate query not the find?
if its only 50 docs size, i . would do like this `Object.bsonsize(db. some_collection.find({}).select("created_at updated_at")).limit(50)`

Comment: `Object.bsonsize` is a **JavaScript** operator. So **NO** you cannot do this using the aggregation framework. Your best option is looping the collection results and passing the current document object to that function, just as existing examples do. You *could* use `mapReduce` since that works via JavaScript, however for what is essentially just *iteration* it would be a rather pointless exercise unless you intended to "group by size" or similar.

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortty I want size of each of the document, not size of all the documents altogether.

Comment: @NeilLunn You're right. It seems like I'll need `mapReduce` or some function to that. But, could you remove the duplicated flag? Both of the links are related to but not the exact answer of this question.

Comment: You really do not want `mapReduce` unless as I stated you actually need some "reducing", and that is not stated in your question. Existing answers directly address what you are asking. A "list" is simply obtained from iteration just like all those examples show. It's really not the job a a database to do those things

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is possible, because of MangoDb add an extra buffer to the document to allow them to grow.

So, the size of the document is not the same as the size of the document on the disk.

However, I found that in many cases just using db.collectionName.stats() is good enough.

See the output example on the image below.

[image]

Comment: In this collection, the size of every document could vary a lot, so `db.collectionName.stats()` does not do much help.